# Avoid printing specific field with jax ws logger?

Tags: java, logging, jax-ws

For trace reasons I need to display the response of a soap webservice, and I do that this way:

```
jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add( new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

it works but, incidentally, the webservice answers with a base64 representation of a pdf file.
Something like this:

```
<response>
    <name>aName</name>
    <description>decription</description>
    <file>...
       loooooooooooong
     ...
    </file>
</response>
```

I want to print only the name and description tags, while for the file tag a simple "obfuscated as too big" string will do.
Is it possible?

Comment: From the one line code I could guess that you are using apache cxf. Is that true? The latest version (3.2.7) has [deprecated](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/LoggingOutInterceptor.html) LoggingOutInterceptor. Have you tried using the suggested alternative i.e. logging module?

Comment: Yes it is indeed deprecated. Could you please point me to a reference to the new module, in particular the part that could help me avoiding printing a specific field?